# Best practices in Application's flow diagram

Tags: object-oriented, documentation, mvc, workflows

I make web applications, mostly MVC, object oriented and database enabled. I always have trouble going back to project after a few months of release and work again. I don't even remember what I made on that project. How should I overcome this problem? I can't afford too much time consuming documentations and so many diagrams. Any quick way you guys practice to avoid this?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lol I'm repeating myself, but simple sequence diagrams (http://websequencediagrams.com) not only define the API methods from the service interactions, but is also a great way to get my head back into it coming back to it later.

Really simple, though. Just enough to understand the high points of client-server interaction.

Also, just a simple bullet point list, even in initial comments of:

- client sends this
- server sends that

is a simple way of capturing that. IMHO